# Is this the correct way to hide a file or folder in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, xampp, localhost

I am just learning more about using classes in PHP. I know the code below is crap has I need help. Can someone just let me know if I am going in the right direction?

```
while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $type = array("index.php", "style.css", "sorttable.js", "host-img");
    if($entryName != $type[0]){
        if($entryName != $type[1]){
            if($entryName != $type[2]){
                if($entryName != $type[3]){
                    $dirArray[]=$entryName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to redeclare the `$type` array in the loop and you can use `in_array`

Comment: Are you asking for a better way or trying to judge the accuracy? You said about hiding, but there is no code about it.

Comment: The whole code is here https://github.com/sammulla47/php-use/blob/main/index.php

Comment: There is definitely a cleaners way to write code Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want is a list of all the files in your directory that do not have one of four specific names.

The code that most resembles yours that would do it more efficiently is

```
$exclude = array("index.php", "style.css", "sorttable.js", "host-img");
$dirArray = [];

while ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    if (!in_array($entryName, $exclude)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can dispense with the loop (as written, will include both files and directories in the directory you supply)

```
$exclude = array("index.php", "style.css", "sorttable.js", "host-img");
$contents = scandir($myDirectory);
$dirArray = array_diff($contents, $exclude);
```

Edit to add for posterity:

@arkascha had an answer that used `array_filter`, and while that example was just an implementation of `array_diff`, the motivation for that pattern is a good one: There may be times when you want to exclude more than just a simple list. It is entirely reasonable, for instance, to imagine you want to exclude specific files *and all directories*. So you have to filter directories from your list. And just for fun, let's also not return any file whose name begins with `.`.

```
$exclude = ["index.php", "style.css", "sorttable.js", "host-img"];
$contents = scandir($myDirectory); // myDirectory is a valid path to the directory

$dirArray = array_filter($contents, function($fileName) use ($myDirectory, $exclude) {
    if (!in_array($fileName, $exclude) && strpos('.', $fileName) !== 0) {
        return !is_dir($myDirectory.$fileName));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `readdir()` takes a directory handle returned from `opendir()`, while `scandir()` takes a string for the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to filter your input:

```
<?php
$input = [".", "..", "folderA", "folderB", "file1", "file2", "file3"];
$blacklist = [".", "..", "folderA", "file1"];
$output = array_filter($input, function($entry) use ($blacklist) {
  return !in_array($entry, $blacklist);
});
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [3] => folderB
    [5] => file2
    [6] => file3
)
```

Such approach allows to implement more complex filter conditions without having to pass over the input data multiple times. For example if you want to add another filter condition based on file name extensions or file creation time, even on file content.